# Texture appearing as stretched in DirectX11

Tags: c#, wpf, directx-11, sharpdx, direct3d11

I'm using DirectX11 with SharpDx & WPF D3DImage in C# to render image as texture.

Previously i was updating my render target (which worked perfectly) and rather not using the pixel shader to display the updated texture within my quad.

Now having realized my mistake i decided to use the pixel shaders so that i can implement letterboxing technique with the help of view port.

In doing so I'm kinda not able to figure out why my rendered texture is a sub region of the image which in turn is displayed as stretched .

Code Used:

**a) Initialisation code**

```
        var device = this.Device;
        var context = device.ImmediateContext;

        byte[] fileBytes = GetShaderEffectsFileBytes();

        var vertexShaderByteCode = ShaderBytecode.Compile(fileBytes, "VSMain", "vs_5_0", ShaderFlags.None, EffectFlags.None);
        var vertexShader = new VertexShader(device, vertexShaderByteCode);
        var pixelShaderByteCode = ShaderBytecode.Compile(fileBytes, "PSMain", "ps_5_0", ShaderFlags.None, EffectFlags.None);
        var pixelShader = new PixelShader(device, pixelShaderByteCode);

        layout = new InputLayout(device, vertexShaderByteCode, new[] {
               new InputElement("SV_Position", 0, Format.R32G32B32A32_Float, 0, 0),
                new InputElement("TEXCOORD", 0, Format.R32G32_Float, 16, 0),
        });

        // Write vertex data to a datastream
        var stream = new DataStream(Utilities.SizeOf<VertexPositionTexture>() * 6, true, true);
        stream.WriteRange(new[]
                       {
                          new VertexPositionTexture(
                        new Vector4(1, 1, 0.5f, 1.0f), // position top-left
                        new Vector2(1.0f, 0.0f)
                        ),
            new VertexPositionTexture(
                        new Vector4(1, -1, 0.5f, 1.0f), // position top-right
                        new Vector2(1.0f, 1.0f)
                        ),
            new VertexPositionTexture(
                        new Vector4(-1, 1, 0.5f, 1.0f), // position bottom-left
                         new Vector2(0.0f, 0.0f)
                        ),
            new VertexPositionTexture(
                        new Vector4(-1, -1, 0.5f, 1.0f), // position bottom-right
                         new Vector2(0.0f, 1.0f)
                        ),
                  });
        stream.Position = 0;

         vertices = new SharpDX.Direct3D11.Buffer(device, stream, new BufferDescription()
        {
            BindFlags = BindFlags.VertexBuffer,
            CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.None,
            OptionFlags = ResourceOptionFlags.None,
            SizeInBytes = Utilities.SizeOf<VertexPositionTexture>() * 6,
            Usage = ResourceUsage.Default,
            StructureByteStride = 0
        });
        stream.Dispose();

        context.InputAssembler.InputLayout = (layout);
        context.InputAssembler.PrimitiveTopology = (PrimitiveTopology.TriangleStrip);
        context.InputAssembler.SetVertexBuffers(0, new VertexBufferBinding(vertices, Utilities.SizeOf<VertexPositionTexture>(), 0));
        context.VertexShader.Set(vertexShader);
        context.GeometryShader.Set(null);
        context.PixelShader.Set(pixelShader);

        Device.ImmediateContext.OutputMerger.SetTargets(m_depthStencilView, m_RenderTargetView);
        this.ImgSource.SetRenderTargetDX11(this.RenderTarget);


        Texture2D flower = Texture2D.FromFile<Texture2D>(this.Device, "3.jpg");
        var srv = new ShaderResourceView(this.Device, flower);
        Device.ImmediateContext.PixelShader.SetShaderResource(0, srv);
        srv.Dispose();
```

**b) VertexPositionTexture**

```
 public struct VertexPositionTexture
{
    public VertexPositionTexture(Vector4 position, Vector2 textureUV)
    {
        Position = position;
        TextureUV = textureUV;
    }

    public Vector4 Position;
    public Vector2 TextureUV;
}
```

**c) Rendering Code**

```
Device.ImmediateContext.ClearRenderTargetView(this.m_RenderTargetView, new Color4(Color.Blue.R, Color.Blue.G, Color.Blue.B, Color.Blue.A));
Device.ImmediateContext.ClearDepthStencilView(m_depthStencilView, DepthStencilClearFlags.Depth, 1.0f, 0);
 Device.ImmediateContext.Draw(4, 0);
 Device.ImmediateContext.Flush();
 this.ImgSource.InvalidateD3DImage();
```

**d) Shader Effects File:**

```
Texture2D ShaderTexture : register(t0);
SamplerState Sampler : register (s0);

struct VertexShaderInput
{
    float4 Position : SV_Position;
    float2 TextureUV : TEXCOORD0;
};

struct VertexShaderOutput
{
    float4 Position : SV_Position;
    float2 TextureUV : TEXCOORD0;
};

VertexShaderOutput VSMain(VertexShaderInput input)
{
    VertexShaderOutput output = (VertexShaderOutput)0;

    output.Position = input.Position;
    output.TextureUV = input.TextureUV;

    return output;
 }

float4 PSMain(VertexShaderOutput input) : SV_Target
{
    return ShaderTexture.Sample(Sampler, input.TextureUV);
}
```

Also below i have added a screenshot of the issue i have been having and actual image that should be rendered.

1. Actual image
   [image]
2. Failed texture rendered
   [image]

Any suggestions or help would be really helpful as I have researched the web and various forums but had no luck .

Thanks.

Link to [Sample Test Application](https://app.box.com/s/x5izsrnoqmkfzix2644t1zyxmrp43ecn)

Comment: Try to simplify your program down to the smallest thing that reproduces the problem.  The general problem with unexpected behavior in 3D graphics programs is that there are many moving parts.  Simplify the problem by eliminating moving parts in order to understand what is going wrong.

Comment: @legalize I've tried to limit to a simplest program. Now I only update the shader resource once and call draw  

Setting ShaderResource `Texture2D flower = Texture2D.FromFile<Texture2D>(this.Device, "3.jpg");
            var srv = new ShaderResourceView(this.Device, flower);
            Device.ImmediateContext.PixelShader.SetShaderResource(0, srv);
            srv.Dispose();`

Calling Draw:
`Device.ImmediateContext.Draw(4, 0);

            Device.ImmediateContext.Flush();
            this.ImgSource.InvalidateD3DImage();`

Hence still not able to figure it out. Any suggestions

Comment: Update the code in your question to the simplest version.

Comment: @legalize as requested I have updated the code in my question

Comment: Your shader annotates the position as screen space (`SV_Position`), but your vertex coordinates are not in screen space.

Comment: @legalize Thanks for the pointer. It was helpful. Also i have finally managed to fix it. It seems my vertices weren't in correct order and the UV coordinates were not correct.